# How to add a string to each line in a file?

Tags: python, string

I need to open a text file and then add a string to the end of each line.

So far:

```
appendlist = open(sys.argv[1], "r").read()
```

Comment: read the documentation for `open`, to begin with.

Answer (score 21):

Remember, using the `+` operator to compose strings is slow. Join lists instead.

```
file_name = "testlorem"
string_to_add = "added"

with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
    file_lines = [''.join([x.strip(), string_to_add, '\n']) for x in f.readlines()]

with open(file_name, 'w') as f:
    f.writelines(file_lines)
```

Comment: Could it be better if ```[''.join([x.strip(), string_to_add, '\n']) for x in f]```?

Comment: with open(file_name, 'w') as f:
        f.writelines(file_lines) 

shouldn't be:

    with open(output, 'w') as f:
        f.writelines(file_lines)

?

Comment: Nope because the same file should be overwritten, but now that you mention it, the `output` variable is unused.

Answer (score 15):

```
s = '123'
with open('out', 'w') as out_file:
    with open('in', 'r') as in_file:
        for line in in_file:
            out_file.write(line.rstrip('\n') + s + '\n')
```

Comment: I tried this and instead of adding the string it puts it on another line. Please note that on the line is an ip. So it should be 127.0.0.1 string instead of 127.0.0.1 (return/enter) string.

Answer (score 3):

```
def add_str_to_lines(f_name, str_to_add):
    with open(f_name, "r") as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        for index, line in enumerate(lines):
            lines[index] = line.strip() + str_to_add + "\n"

    with open(f_name, "w") as f:
        for line in lines:
            f.write(line)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    str_to_add = " foo"
    f_name = "test"
    add_str_to_lines(f_name=f_name, str_to_add=str_to_add)

    with open(f_name, "r") as f:
        print(f.read())
```