# Trying to insert a character $ for beginning and end of a string using python, but i got them just in the beginning

Tags: python

I have a .txt file that contain as below:

text line1

text line2

text line3

.

.

text line n

I am trying to insert a char $ to the start and end of each line, I should get like this:

$text line1$

$text line2$

$text line3$

.

.

$text line n$

my code is :

```
Read_data = open("finename.txt","r")
text_line = Read_data.readline()

while text_line:
   text_line = '$' + text_line + '$'
   Write_data = open('newfile.txt', 'a')
   Write_data.write(text_line)
   text_line = Read_data.readline()
   Write_data.close()
```

the output I got like this :

$text line1

$$text line2

$$text line3

.

.

.

$$text line n

$

any idea why getting that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember that you need to strip the `\n` character on each line. Check this post [Python Add string to each line in a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20273889/python-add-string-to-each-line-in-a-file).
 This should work for your code (following the suggestion of opening the files outside the loop):

```
Read_data = open("finename.txt","r")
Write_data = open('newfile.txt', 'a')

for text_line in Read_data.readline():
    text_line = '$' + text_line.strip() + '$\n'
    Write_data.write(text_line)

Write_data.close()
```

Comment: you correct about stripping character for each line but with for loop I could not get the intended output so I am going to answer it below with while loop and that works.

Comment: Good that you noticed that @Ahmed, I just copied the code there with the fix I thought would work, but better if we have the right one ;)

Comment: And if we get rid of the `readline()` and just use `for text_line in Read_data` the code will be even more pythonic.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that `text` has a trailing newline character, and you are putting the $ *after* it.  Try:

```
text = '$' + text[:-1] + '$\n'
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to open both files outside the loop, then loop over the available input lines. Something like this:

```
Read_data = open("finename.txt","r")
Write_data = open('newfile.txt', 'a')

for text_line in Read_data.readlines():
    formatted_text_line = '$' + text_line + '$'
    Write_data.write(formatted_text_line)

Write_data.close()
```

You may also need to add a newline to the written line to get what you want:

```
    formatted_text_line = '$' + text_line + '$\n'
```

Comment: `.readline()` returns only one line.  You will be iterating through each character of the first line.  Even if you meant `.readlines()`, though, the newline character at the end of each line would still cause double dollar signs at the beginning and nothing at the end.

Comment: @srowland your answer not helpful

Comment: I did @zondo - thanks, and you're right about the newline - I'd missed that part :).

Answer (score 1):

I am correcting @Vladir Parrado Cruz using while loop instead of for loop, coz with for loop you will get different output:

```
Read_data = open("finename.txt","r")
Write_data = open('newfile.txt', 'a')
text_line = Read_data.readline()
while text_line:
    text_line = '$' + text_line.strip() + '$\n'
    Write_data.write(text_line)
    text_line = Read_data.readline()
Write_data.close()
```