# how to add random values to the column of a csv file?

Tags: python, csv

I want to append a column in a prefilled csv file with 3 million rows using python. Then, i want to fill the column with random values in the range of (1, 50). something like this:

input csv file,

awareness  trip  amount

25          1      30

30          2      35

output csv file,

awareness  trip  amount  size

25          1      30     49

30          2      35     20

how can i do this?
the code i have written is as follows:

with open('2019-01-1.csv', 'r') as CSVIN: with open('2019-01-2.csv', 'w') as

CSVOUT:

CSVWrite = csv.writer(CSVOUT, lineterminator='\n') CSVRead =

csv.reader(CSVIN)

CSVWrite = csv.writer(CSVOUT, lineterminator='\n')

```
    CSVRead = csv.reader(CSVIN)

    NewDict = []

    row = next(CSVRead)

    row.append('Size')

    NewDict.append(row)

    print(NewDict.append(row))

    for row in CSVRead:

        randSize = np.random.randint(1, 50)

        row.append(row[0])

        NewDict.append(row)

    CSVWrite.writerows(NewDict)
```

Comment: Can you show us the code you tried for reading the CSV and adding the random numbers, so that we can help? (If you don't know how to read data from a CSV, try https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html)

Comment: with open('2019-01-1.csv', 'r') as CSVIN:
    with open('2019-01-2.csv', 'w') as CSVOUT:
        CSVWrite = csv.writer(CSVOUT, lineterminator='\n')
        CSVRead = csv.reader(CSVIN)

Comment: What about the code to add the random numbers? What have you tried?

Comment: Please put your code in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this answer: [Python Add string to each line in a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20273889/python-add-string-to-each-line-in-a-file)

I've found it much easier to use `with` for files instead of importing csv or other special filetype libraries unless my use case is very specific.
So in your case, it would be something like:

```
input_file_name = "2019-01-1.csv"
output_file_name = "2019-01-2.csv"
with open(input_file_name, 'r') as f:
    file_lines = [''.join([x, ",Size,{}".format(random.randint(1, 50)), '\n']) for x in f.readlines()]

with open(output_file_name, 'w') as f:
    f.writelines(file_lines)
```

Comment: thank you dear Slickwarren. the code you have just mentioned can generate random numbers but not under the generated header 'size'.

Comment: dear Slickwarren, this code generate a separate row with a random size in front of it, one in between rows, i wanted something like this: awareness trip amount size. 'Size' must be added as the last header of the column and under it, the random generated values must be add, as i mentioned in the above code.